# pH of salt composed of the conjugate of strong acid and base

Tags: acid-base, ph

salt like [HA]B dissloves in water (here we don't consider its solubility) :
$$\ce{HA <=>[$K_\mathrm a$] A- + H+}$$

and

$$\ce{B- + H2O <=>[$K_\mathrm b$] HB + OH-}$$

> usually we combine two and get 
>   $$\ce{HA + B- <=> A- + HB}$$
>
> (Ex: $\ce{NH4CN}$)
>
> and suggest this to be the dominant reaction so as 
>   to calculate pH
>
> **that is , the  amount of HA and $\ce{B-}$ being consumed are assumed to be the same**
>
> let x be the amount being consumed and solve  $\frac{x^2}{(C-x)^2}=\frac{K_aK_b}{K_w}$  where C is the initial concentration of the salt

My question is: **under what circumstance the suggestion their amount (being consumed) are the same would be invalid ?**

( Maybe both of $K_\mathrm a$ and $K_\mathrm b$ is really closed to $K_\mathrm w$ and three of their dissociation must be carefully inspected to get the right answer ? )

**and if this is the case, how to solve it ?**

Comment: It would be helpful if you organize this a bit. Describe the type of problems you want to solve, with a blockquote, then demonstrate your approach and ask where the strategy won't work. This was flagged as unclear, and I have to agree with the close reason unless you [edit] this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For strong acid and base, the reaction from H+ and A- to HA simply 'happens negligibly' because of the common ion phenomenon. So, the conjugate base of acid (or vice versa) is considered neutral.
(that's why we don't taste any sour or bitterness from NaCl)